# Reply Markup Keyboard To Enter Text In Field Not Send

Tags: telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I am reading about telegram keyboards for bots (see picture)

[image]

From as far i can gather pressing of these button will instantly send the text in the chat.
What i want is the keyboards send the text to the message field.

For example -
if i press 1 ,the message field shows 1 then pressing * and 1 will result in 1*1 which will be sent to bot

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not allowed by Telegram Bot APIs, because as soon as you press a button, it instantly sends a message with the same text.

The only thing you can do is receive every message and put them together. you have also to define a workflow using states, for example